# How to fill left class div with color?

Tags: html, css

I need .left class to have been fully filled with red colour if the right class has content in it. At the moment it doesn't fully fill in the color to the left div? I believe problem is with height?
How can I achieve it?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 8px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="radio" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not set the background red color on the container instead?

Comment: because the in the second div there shouldn't be a colour, I gave it as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `align-items: center;` to `align-items: stretch;` in the `.container`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* <-- Change this */
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 8px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="radio" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```